# Echo/Print variables for debugging which GD image seems to hide

Tags: php

I have a site which displays a dynamically generated GD image (data pulled from SQL). I need to view this image to pinpoint inconsistencies in my coding. These aren't errors, but rather just simple variables that are out of place that I must isolate. The easiest way I've found to do this is to simply echo the variables at different points in the code.

The problem is that the GD Image will overlay the page and so nothing is displayed from echo/print. The only way I can call the variables/functions the way I want to is by clicking on unique spots on this image. So the image must be there to echo the correct php variables. Both must be present at the same time. The only way I can echo/print is to turn off the image, but then these variables tell me nothing without being able to look at the image.

I don't want to use breakpoints/debugging etc as I'm on a shared host and don't have access to the extensions required for this, and I don't want to run a server locally for development.

I'm pulling the image in an img src="image.php" tag, and the PHP is stored in an external file called functions.php. The index.html which brings it all together is just jquery/javascript.

How can I echo the outputs with the GD image still displayed?

Comment: if you can't use a debugger and can't run a local server (how are you even developing without a local server? that's odd). you could try saving logs to a database/file and look at them after the script has ran

Comment: That would be perfect if I could write let's say.. $var => some_log.txt specifically within the code. Would that be possible?

Comment: Would 'view source' of the web page show all of the messages?

Comment: @NigelRen unfortunately not since this would be php/server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output your debugging to the log.

```
error_log('Your message here...');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: @user4779 No problem.  If it works for you, you can choose to accept this answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could buffer the output of the script using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)/[`ob_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) and then use [`imagestring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) to draw those logs on the image like so:

```php
ob_start();
echo("Foo");
$out = ob_get_contents();
imagestring($image, 5, 0, 0, $out, imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255));
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: This does sound ideal but I can't see how I'd get it to work unfortunately. Since the image is already drawn in a separate file image.php to functions.php, the $image variable is missing. When I try to require image.php then the functions.php won't load. But would be nice to draw the variables somehow.